# TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, reddit

### Error

```
/Users/sharanduggirala/Documents/UID/CS235ProjectJS/node_modules/reddit-oauth/lib/index.js:278t-development-environment@1.0.0~preinstall: javascript-development-environment@1.0.0
        if (query.state !== state || !query.code) {
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
    at RedditApi__oAuthTokens [as oAuthTokens] (/Users/sharanduggirala/Documents/UID/CS235ProjectJS/node_modules/reddit-oauth/lib/index.js:278:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sharanduggirala/Documents/UID/CS235ProjectJS/buildScripts/srcReddit.js:30:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at loader (/Users/sharanduggirala/Documents/UID/CS235ProjectJS/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/sharanduggirala/Documents/UID/CS235ProjectJS/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
    at /Users/sharanduggirala/Documents/UID/CS235ProjectJS/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:159:24
```

---

### Code

I am currently trying to use the [Reddit API](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/), and am trying to get the example on [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reddit-oauth) page to work. This is the error that I got when trying to compile the code below:

```
var RedditApi = require('reddit-oauth');
var request = require('request');

var reddit = new RedditApi({
    app_id: **********,
    app_secret: ********* ,
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8888'
});

// Authenticate with username/password
reddit.passAuth(
    'sharan100',
    '********',
    function (success) {
        if (success) {
            // Print the access token we just retrieved
            console.log(reddit.access_token);
        }
    }
);

// Get the OAuth URL to redirect users to
// Scopes are defined here: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2
reddit.oAuthUrl('some_state', 'identity');

// After the user is redirected back to us, grab the query string
// object and exchange it for a set of access and refresh tokens.
// Scope has to be identical as the one provided to oAuthUrl. Can
// change for each authentication attempt.
reddit.oAuthTokens(
    'some_state',
    request.query,
    function (success) {
        // Print the access and refresh tokens we just retrieved
        console.log(reddit.access_token);
        console.log(reddit.refresh_token);
    }
);
```

---

### Request

The output of `console.log('request')` is:

```
{ [Function: request]
  get: [Function],
  head: [Function],
  options: [Function],
  post: [Function],
  put: [Function],
  patch: [Function],
  del: [Function],
  delete: [Function],
  jar: [Function],
  cookie: [Function],
  defaults: [Function],
  forever: [Function],
  Request:
   { [Function: Request]
     super_:
      { [Function: Stream]
        super_: [Object],
        Readable: [Object],
        Writable: [Object],
        Duplex: [Object],
        Transform: [Object],
        PassThrough: [Object],
        Stream: [Circular],
        _isUint8Array: [Function: isUint8Array],
        _uint8ArrayToBuffer: [Function: _uint8ArrayToBuffer] },
     debug: undefined,
     defaultProxyHeaderWhiteList:
      [ 'accept',
        'accept-charset',
        'accept-encoding',
        'accept-language',
        'accept-ranges',
        'cache-control',
        'content-encoding',
        'content-language',
        'content-location',
        'content-md5',
        'content-range',
        'content-type',
        'connection',
        'date',
        'expect',
        'max-forwards',
        'pragma',
        'referer',
        'te',
        'user-agent',
        'via' ],
     defaultProxyHeaderExclusiveList: [ 'proxy-authorization' ] },
  initParams: [Function: initParams],
  debug: [Getter/Setter] }
```

**Note**: Code has been edited to reflect the comments below.

---

Not sure why this code seems to be getting the errors above.

Comment: The error means that `query` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Pointy how should the `query` be defined

Comment: Have you debugged and looked at the state of the request object?  
I'm willing to bet that the request object just does not have the query property defined. In other words, `request.query === undefined`.

Comment: @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy The code upto that point has been updated on the question.

Comment: Try `console.log(request)` before you call `reddit.oAuthTokens`. What is in that request object? Do you see `query` or not?

Comment: @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy I don't see a query. Is the code on the example wrong? Am I importing the wrong `request`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this isn't valid:

```
reddit.oAuthTokens(
    'some_state',
    // this
    request.query,
    function (success) {
        // Print the access and refresh tokens we just retrieved
        console.log(reddit.access_token);
        console.log(reddit.refresh_token);
    }
);
```

it's like doing `const request.query = 'asdf'`

try instead (destructure query off request):

```
const { query } = request
// or: var query = request.query

reddit.oAuthTokens(
    'some_state',
    // this
    query,
    function (success) {
        // Print the access and refresh tokens we just retrieved
        console.log(reddit.access_token);
        console.log(reddit.refresh_token);
    }
);
```

Comment: `if (query.state !== state || !query.code) {` it's pointing to query.state indicating that query is not defined, so somewhere in your file, you are referring to `query` without defining it, meaning it needs to be defined like `var query = 'something'` or it needs to be passed into a function like `function(something, query) { ... }` That or `query.state` is not defined but `query.code` is. Your missing is to find out why the code executes `if (query.state !== state || !query.code) {` before `query.state` gets created or added.

Comment: I can't help you any further until you show me everywhere that `query` comes from. I don't see it in your file, which may be related to your problem because its saying "who is query" when it goes to calculate if `query.state` is not equal to `state`. Your code is currently passing it into `reddit.oAuthTokens()`, but *WHERE* does query come from.